# How to make Plupload zones that will survive changes in core?

Tags: uploads, javascript, plupload

I had recently implemented custom Plupload form in a plugin (located in admin area and working with SVG files).

Plupload has half a ton of settings, provided *for WP's own* upload zone by [`wp_plupload_default_settings()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_plupload_default_settings/), from which I had to copy settings out and customize.

Now in upcoming 3.9 core release those settings are getting changed (see [Plupload 2.x in WordPress 3.9](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/11/plupload-2-x-in-wordpress-3-9/)), which would likely blow my custom upload up, at least partially.

How do I implemented Plupoad in a way that won't fall apart every time core changes related bits and won't interfere with arbitrary upload zones in core or other plugins/themes?

This is settings I ended up with so far (they might not be perfect, but they got it done):

```
public function get_uploader_settings() {

    return array(
        'runtimes'            => 'html5,silverlight,flash,html4',
        'browse_button'       => 'cdd-plupload-browse-button',
        'container'           => 'cdd-plupload-upload-ui',
        'drop_element'        => 'cdd-drag-drop-area',
        'file_data_name'      => 'async-upload',
        'multiple_queues'     => true,
        'max_file_size'       => wp_max_upload_size() . 'b',
        'url'                 => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'flash_swf_url'       => includes_url( 'js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf' ),
        'silverlight_xap_url' => includes_url( 'js/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap' ),
        'filters'             => array( array( 'title' => __( 'Allowed Files' ), 'extensions' => 'svg' ) ),
        'multipart'           => true,
        'urlstream_upload'    => true,
        'multi_selection'     => false,
        'multipart_params'    => array(
            '_ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'media-form' ),
            'action'      => 'upload-attachment',
            'post_id'     => get_the_ID(),
            'cdd-upload'  => true,
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey @Rarst, can you provide a little bit more details on what exactly breaks? Is it just the swf/xap URLs an the max filesize filter or is there something else? It'd be also helpful if you provided some sample code and we can try to figure some back-compat things out. Thanks!

Comment: @kovshenin added settings-related code to the question. I hadn't tested this out with 3.9 since essentially this is part of completed work-for-hire, which I am not currently working on (likely to be working on it further though in near future).

Comment: Cool! I can think of two potential solutions here. One is if core's `wp_plupload_default_settings()` function was simply more generic in a way you could use outside of `wp.Uploader` and `wp.media`. Second is to try and decouple `wp.Uploader` from media and have plugins use that instead. Inside we can provide back-compat code for things like `max_file_size`. Thoughts?

Comment: @kovshenin for starters I would be happy getting those `$defaults` from `wp_plupload_default_settings()` without its side effects. I could probably handle this in JS, but this assume native stuff _is enabled_, for generic case / public code would be too fragile.

Comment: Actually 2.1.1 seems to provide backwards compatibility for `max_file_size` and `filters` [ref](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/src/plupload.js#L1155), so I guess the only things we're missing are the paths to the swf/xap files...

Comment: if we renamed Moxie.swf and .xap back to plupload.flash.swf and plupload.silverlight.xap, would this unbreak your plugin for 3.9?

Comment: @kovshenin if rest is backwards compat on Plupload level then likely. The Q is more about long view though — or we would be here again next time something changes. :)

Comment: @kovshenin rather than renaming old values could be filtered in `includes_url()` maybe?

Comment: I thought about that at first, but seems overkill to filter every single call to `includes_url()` to look for plupload strings that in 99% of the cases won't even exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like core just needs a better way to handle backwards compatibility with Plupload at the WordPress level :) You as a plugin developer shouldn't have to worry about that, your usage looks fair, given that there currently is no other way to obtain that default settings array.

I've opened [#27763](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27763) to address this and some other compatibility issues with the Plupload update. Feel free to add to the list if anything else pops up.